# What is the best way of having a connected handwriting recognizer?

Tags: tesseract

I tried to train tesseract with unconnected letters and it is working nice.

But i wonder if i can recognize handwriting with connected letters.

I am more interseted in open source methods.

Thanks for any idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't find any open source handwriting recognizer that suports cursive.